# Checking if value exists in database using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a form in extjs where the user insert some data and click on a save button. However one of the inserted data (NUMBER) needs not to exist in the database table in order for the form to be accepted. I applied a condition using Ajax to check if the number exists in the database. If yes an alert pops, else a scripts executes. I tried several things but it's not working. Any help?

```
var Number = record.getField("NUMBER").getRealValue();

var key = null;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Records?DBName=EMP&TableName=EMP_HISTORY",
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
        "Where": "NUMBER ='" + Number + "'"
    },
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('record').each(function() {
            key = $(this).find("PKEY").text();
        });

        if (key) {
            if(key != null){
            alert("Lease Number already exists.");
            }
        else{
             for (var i = 1; i < tabPanel.items.length; i++) {
                 tabPanel.items.get(i).setDisabled(false);
          }
          tabPanel.setActiveTab(2);
          tabPanel.setActiveTab(1);


        }
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What does *"not working"* mean?  Also, trying to assign something to the native [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object looks like a pretty silly thing to do...

Comment: If you haven't been warned.. There is a HUGE potential for SQL injection if you're using the "Where" parameter as is in the back end (which is probably what you're doing based on your code)